# Как заменить значение цвета на сам цвет в строке?

Tags: java

У меня есть строка

`String str = "#ff3276Привет #ff3f7fкак #ff6698дела?";`

И есть метод `ChatColor.of(String string);`, который превращает лишь HEX код в цвет.

Я хотел бы узнать, каким способом я мог бы изменить все HEX коды в строке на цвета, используя метод: `Chatcolor.of(String str);`

Сейчас я использую что-то типа:
`String string = (ChatColor.of("#ff3276") + "Привет " + ChatColor.of("#ff3f7f") + "как " + ChatColor.of("#ff6698") + "дела?");`

Если будет проще, до допускается взять цветовые кода в какие-то скобки, например:

`String str = "{#ff3276}Привет {#ff3f7f}как {#ff6698}дела?";`

Comment: я бы написал класс, какой нить ColoredText  с полями Color и Text, и хранил бы список или массив таких классов.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Интересная задача.

### `String.format`

Программировать будет проще если поменять входные данные. Вызов будет выглядеть так:

```
Colorizer1.colorize("%sПривет %sкак %sдела?", "#ff3276", "#ff3f7f", "#ff6698");
```

Реализация простая: пробегаем по всем цветам, обрабатываем их `ChatColor.of`, вызываем `String.format`:

```
public class Colorizer1 {
    public static String colorize(String s, String... colors) {
        Object[] chatColors = new Object[colors.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < colors.length; ++i) {
            chatColors[i] = ChatColor.of(colors[i]);
        }
        return String.format(s, chatColors);
    }
}
```

Недостатка два: другой формат вызова, в строке не должно быть других [format specifiers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html). Их нужно экранировать удваивая знаки процента: `%%s -> %s`.

### `regex`

Это способ работает прямо как попрошено:

```
Colorizer2.colorize("#ff3276Привет #ff3f7fкак #ff6698дела?")
```

Реализация через регулярные выражения. `#[0-9a-fA-F]{6}` находит в строке описания цветов. Описания обрабатывются `ChatColor.of`. Все кусочки собираются в `StringBuilder`:

```
import java.util.regex.MatchResult;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Colorizer2 {
    public static String colorize(String s) {
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("#[0-9a-fA-F]{6}");

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
        int lastEnd = 0;
        while (matcher.find()) {
            MatchResult matchResult = matcher.toMatchResult();
            int start = matchResult.start();
            int end = matchResult.end();
            sb.append(s.substring(lastEnd, start));
            sb.append(ChatColor.of(s.substring(start, end)));
            lastEnd = end;
        }
        sb.append(s.substring(lastEnd));
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

И здесь не без проблем: нет способа отключить механизм. Вы вообще не можете напечатать строку с кодом цвета в чате - она будет заменена на цветовой код.

Это можно исправить, но надо изобрести дополнительный синтаксис наподобие экранирования `%%s`.